# Swiper js showing 3 identical slides when there is one slide

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm trying to have 3 visible slides in the page. The problem is that whenever there are less than 3 slides those slides are duplicated to fill also the empty spaces so, for instance, if I have just one slide it shows three identical copies of the same slide.
Is there any way to avoid that ? I would like just the single slide to be shown.

Here's the configuration of the swiper:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.campaign-slider-two', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    breakpoints: {
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        767: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.campaign-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    loop: true,
});
```

I took a look at the Swiper documentation but I couldn't find anything about this kind of configurations.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Simply change the `loop` parameter from `true` to `false`

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem but having an infinite loop is quite common. One way would be to dynamically add loop.

Answer (score 1):

**ADD THESE LINES BEFORE CREATING YOUR SWIPER**

```
const swiper = this.swiper;
swiper.loopDestroy();
swiper.loopCreate();
```

For Example:

```
const swiper = this.swiper;
swiper.loopDestroy();
swiper.loopCreate();

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { 
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
});`
```

Answer (score 1):

Manually destroying the loop after initializing swiper worked for me as suggested on this [github](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/2629) issue:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.campaign-slider-two', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    breakpoints: {
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        767: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        },
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.campaign-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    loop: true,
});


swiper.loopDestroy();
```

It allows you have loop but would not create any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance how many items there will be, you can set `slidesPerView` accordingly:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.campaign-slider-two', {
    slidesPerView: Math.min(items.length, 3),
    spaceBetween: 0,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    breakpoints: {
        768: {
            slidesPerView: Math.min(items.length, 2),
        },
        767: {
            slidesPerView: Math.min(items.length, 1),
        },
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.campaign-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    loop: true,
});
```